# PHPMail GMAIL - No route to host (65) SMTP connect() failed.

Tags: ssl, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I'm having an error when trying to send emails using PHPMailer through gmail server. I cannot say what is the problem I triple checked the code google it without finding why is this happening. Yesterday was working perfectly today I wake up try it again and sends this error.

The error is the following:

SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: No route to host (65) SMTP connect() failed.

The code is this:

```
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
$query = "SELECT email FROM rnmembers WHERE user='$user'";
$result  = queryMysql($query);
$user_email_array = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$user_email = $user_email_array[0];

require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('content.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com";        // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                                  // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
// 1 = errors and messages
// 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                               // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com";        // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                                // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "email@gmail.com";    // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "password";                      // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('oscar.panczenko.web@gmail.com', 'Virtual Tutors');
//$mail->AddReplyTo("email@gmail.com","Web Master");
$mail->Subject    = "Your training appointment - Virtual Tutor.";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = $user_email;
$mail->AddAddress($address, $user);
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo "<br/ ><br />Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    echo "<br />";
}
else
{
    echo "<br /><br />Message sent!<br />";
}
```

Any hints?

Kind regards.

Oscar.

Answer (score 1):

Reason of the error: When connecting from different network google mail server won't let your web app to connect.

The reason of this problem was not on the code or my local server. The error appeared when I changed my connection to a different hotspot.

1) Working from home: Working perfectly.
2) Went to McDonalds (I was starving): Suddenly error appeared.
3) Changed hotspot: Working perfectly again.

I noticed that my mobile phone when connected to the McDonald's hotspot stop receiving emails from my gmail account, and said it has problems with the SMTP connection as well.

Later I found another person had the same problem when changing countries [here](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail/frYh5gwfgaE/xxSu5ilWrwMJ).

Also when trying to access directly to this Gmail account I had the following prompt:

[image: Mobile verification.]

So if your server is using google mail SMTP be sure to take this into account before changing your servers network connection.

Please if anybody has further information on the topic share it.

Regards.

Oscar.